# Linking Opus codec with VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opus

## Having problems with Opus codec on VS 2010 even after linking .lib(libopusfile-0.lib and opus.lib) file ?

Getting same errors:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _opus_decoder_destroy referenced in function _main
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _opus_encoder_destroy referenced in function _main
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _opus_decode referenced in function _main
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _opus_encode referenced in function _main
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _opus_decoder_create referenced in function _main
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _opus_encoder_ctl referenced in function _main
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _opus_strerror referenced in function _main
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _opus_encoder_create referenced in function _main
>
> 1>C:\Users\korisnik\Desktop\Projekti\opus\Opus\Debug\Opus.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals

I am new to this and stuck with this problem for a while now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: improving formatting

Answer (score 0):

OPUS has multiple libs so make sure you link with all of them.